# Xamarin (C# Android) SMSManager SendText() failure with Result_Ok

Tags: android, xamarin, smsmanager

I'm building an application consisting of an automatic SMS sender in Xamarin .

```
//This is part of larger class
public void Send()
{
SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage(DestinationNumber, null, Message,SentPendingIntent, null);    
}
```

If I use a Huawei P10Pro ( Api level 28 , v9.0)the SMSs are delivered despite that the default messaging app do not show them. But if I switch to another phone , a Samsung A21(API Level 30 ,v11.0) no SMS's are delivered but they appear in the default messaging app. The ResultCode of the PendingIntent will be -1(Result_Ok) for both phones.

Also if I take the Sim card out of any phone the ResultCode will be RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE so the PendingIntent works properly i guess.

I see SMSManager.Default is deprecated . Could this cause the issue?

PS:I did not add more code because I feel my issue lies outside of the code itself and I was not willing to create a too long post

Comment: `no SMS's are delivered but they appear in the default messaging app`   I don't quite understand what you mean.  Since no SMS are delivered,why the sms appear in the default messaging app. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: So my application is not the system default messaging app , it's just calling that default app for actually sending the messages using SMS Manager . The SMS's appear in that app as delivered ( you can read them and if you select one and long press in order to "See message details" Status of message is set to Sent) but the receiver actually doesn't get any message . The point is the default messaging app says its delivered but its not .I can't tell why they appear in the app or why they are not sent . That is my question as well .